# How to determine the convergence/divergence of an improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(ax) - \arctan(bx)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

**How to determine the convergence/divergence of an improper integral:**
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(ax) - \arctan(bx)}{x}dx
$$
I know that this integral can be written into the sum of two integrals by the additivity property:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(ax) - \arctan(bx)}{x}dx + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan(ax) - \arctan(bx)}{x}dx
$$
In order for the original integral to converge, it is necessary that each of the two integrals obtained converges, if one of them diverges, then the original integral also diverges. I do not quite understand how to determine the divergence/convergence of the two integrals obtained, I am confused by 2 parameters (a and b), nothing effective comes to mind, how to simply consider the parameters a and b separately. Is there any more concise and effective determining to separating the convergence/divergence of these two integrals?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046074/show-that-int-0-infty-fracfax-fbxxdx-f0-l-ln-fracba

Comment: This is a Frullani integral.

Comment: as usual, no one wants to think, really why think when a simple integral can be swatted by a big theorem. as a result, I figured out this question myself and dispensed with using Frulani's theorem, I wanted to publish a solution a little later without using Frulani's theorem, but the moderators - people who really have nothing to do in life except sit on this forum and earn a reputation - the only thing they can be proud of and brag about in their lives, closed this question